# Search in a php string for a count of numbers

Tags: php

I have variables like this:

```
Example 1: 709000-037602-14-5_ABC
Example 2: 702000-025801-12_4_DEF
Example 3: 210104-1041-011866_GHI
```

How can i cut the data?
My idea is to seach for the underscore BUT the example 1 does cut on the false segment.

I want to get this variables: $var=709000-037602-14-4, $var=709000-037602-14_4 and $var1=210104-1041-011866

(ABC, DEF, GHI are not important. I only wanted to show i cant search for it.)

For now my used function is:

```
$var= strstr($var_original, '_', true);
```

Question: Can I count the number of numbers on the secound sequment (037602, 025801 or 1041) because this is 6 OR 4 digits.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: If your source strings have a similar structure, you could also describe that with a regular expression and match via one of php's preg_* functions. Something like `^\d+-(?:\d{6}|\d{4})-(?:\d+[-_]?)+(?=_)` should work for your examples.

Comment: See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LTEL5L/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [array_pop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)
- [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode)

Like:

```
   $string =  '709000-037602-14-5_ABC';
   $string1 = '702000-025801-12_4_DEF';
 
   echo explodeCode($string).'<br>'. explodeCode($string1);
   function explodeCode($code){
     $final = explode('_', $code);
     array_pop($final);
     return (count($final) === 2) ? implode('_', $final) : implode('', $final);
   }
```

Output:

```
709000-037602-14-5
702000-025801-12_4
```

---

After your multiple example i suppose is better use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/preg_split) like:

```
$string =  '709000-037602-14-5_ABC';
$string1 = '702000-025801-12_4_DEF';
$string2 = '709000-037602-14-5_ABC_test_no1';
echo explodeCode($string).'<br>'. explodeCode($string1). '<br>'. explodeCode($string2);
function explodeCode($code){
   return preg_split("/\_[A-Z]/", $code)[0];
}
```

Output:

```
709000-037602-14-5
702000-025801-12_4
709000-037602-14-5
```

Comment: Thx i will test it but i want to cut after 12_4 not 12.

Comment: So the exit point have to be in the example 1 und 3 the first _ and in example 2 the secound _

Comment: thx @simone but if i get "709000-037602-14-5_ABC_test_no1" for the string i get no good result. Can you help me once again? Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you soooo much for helping. One error i detect (sry). Can you help me last time :)? Problem with: "709000-051946-17/1_van der Mopen_Ulo 1016"